# Correct Date Format Validation of a Date

Tags: c#, asp.net, date, datetime

```
Label gdate=(Label)(GridView1.Rows[i].FindControl("Date"));
```

Now what i want is to make sure that the date(or value) in variable **gdate** is a valid date(ShortDate like **14-03-2014**) without time (not like **14-03-2014 00:00:00** which is **invalid**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use DateTime `TryParseEaxct` if the exact format needs checking:

```
DateTime dateValue
if (DateTime.TryParseExact(gdate.Text, "dd-MM-yyyy", null, 
                       DateTimeStyles.None, out dateValue))
{
    //Date in correct format
    //use dateValue
}
else
{
    //Date in incorrect format
}
```

`Convert.ToDateTime` will throw an exception if the datetime cannot be parsed.

`ParseExact` will also throw an exception if the date string in your `Date` control is empty.

Comment: Not working!
Still comparing the gdate.Text with dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss


I want to compare gdate.Text with dd-MM-yyyy only

Comment: If your date is of this format `14-03-2014 00:00:00` and the `TryParseExact` is checking for `dd-MM-yyyy` only, it would surely not parse. What exactly is not working?

Comment: assume this--> value of gdate is 20-03-2014, not when im comparing this value according to the code u gave it is not getting validated because "out dateValue" is of format of dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss and the value of gdate is of dd-MM-yyyy only

Comment: i want to compare value of gdate with dd-MM-yyyy only

Comment: `out` dateValue is what is known as out parameters in c#. When TryParseExact() successfully parses the string you provide to it, it would create a DateTime object and put it in `dateValue`. Now when you  provide `"14-03-2014"` to this function, it would correctly parse and the `dateValue` would now contain a DateTime object representing   14th March 2014. Now this created object would also have as hours minutes and seconds all zeroes because those are their default values.

Comment: Oops, you are right, its working now...Thankqqqqq :)

Answer (score 0):

A CustomValidator here:

```
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server"
    ID="valDateRange" 
    ControlToValidate="txtDatecompleted"
    onservervalidate="valDateRange_ServerValidate" 
    ErrorMessage="enter valid date" />
```

Server Side:

```
protected void valDateRange_ServerValidate(object source, ServerValidateEventArgs args)
{
    DateTime minDate = DateTime.Parse("1000/12/28");
    DateTime maxDate = DateTime.Parse("9999/12/28");
    DateTime dt;

    args.IsValid = (DateTime.TryParse(args.Value, out dt) 
                    && dt <= maxDate 
                    && dt >= minDate);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use short date function for date format, like

```
 DateTime dt=new DateTime();
 dt = DateTime.Now;
 MessageBox.Show(dt.ToShortDateString());
```

Comment: I'm not trying to convert value of gdate, i'm trying to compare it with dd-MM-yyyy only, not even with dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
gdate.Text = DateTime.Now.Date.ToShortDateString();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to convert value of gdate, i'm trying to compare it with dd-MM-yyyy only, not even with dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss

Answer (score 0):

Try this one to store formated date

```
string chkin = txtCheckIn.Text;
DateTime CheckIn = DateTime.ParseExact(chkin, "MM/dd/yyyy", System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```